# What CMS would you recommend for this?

Tags: javascript, php, cms

I have a website idea that combines a sort of Wikipedia styled article system that is vast BUT at the same time LOOKS great! I want to have many, many articles but also have a lot of pictures, beautiful headers/logos and picture galleries. Also it should also have social media buttons.

What would be a good CMS for this?

I have experience with HTML, CSS, JavaScript and I could probably learn PHP if needed.

Comment: Does it need to be editable by one person, a private group, or anyone? Do you need a search feature?

Comment: @Nicolas I will edit it by myself. I definitely need a search feature!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Drupal its CMS, and has a lot flexibility.

For wiki's and social & Search, Drupal is a really good choice. Its written in PHP, which is also easy to pick up.

There is also a lot of modules for you to use

Here is a distribution already made for what you are looking for [Drupal Wiki](https://drupal.org/project/drupal_wiki)

Answer (score 0):

If you have experience with HTML, CSS and Javascript, use [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki/de). MediaWiki is the software behind Wikipedia. So if you want to get something similar to Wikipedia, but have a better design, the simplest ida is to use the same software and adjust the design.

Comment: For some reasone, this reminded me of this "old" (2 years?) Wikipedia make-over ploy: [Wikipedia Redefined](http://wikipediaredefined.com/) (and the [agency blog](http://newisnew.lt/en/wikipedia-redefined) that was responsible). I quite like it. :)